# How can I assign a static IP to a pod with OpenShift SDN?

Tags: openshift

Please, please don't tell me this is an anti-pattern. I know it is. I want to do it anyway.

Comment: You can't, but you can assign what egress IP it would appear to use when connections exit the cluster. Is that what you want? See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#enabling-static-ips-for-external-project-traffic

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that as of now. You can use the ClusterIP / Egress IP in service instead.